# How can I create an NSMutableDictionary from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to figure out the best way to sort an `NSMutableDictionary`. I have a dictionary of Card keys (i.e. aceSpades) that store Card values (i.e. 14). I have then been using an `NSMutableArray` to shuffle the 52 Card keys into an array called shuffledCards. Finally I make another array from shuffledCards thats takes a portion (15) of shuffledCards and puts them into an array called computerHand.

The new array computerHand is not good enough because I need to be able to connect the Card values with the Card keys. What I really need to do is create a new `NSMutableDictionary` for computerHand from the array shuffledCards so that I can sort it by Card values and still be able to retrieve the Card keys.

I'm thinking I need something like this, where currentCard is the first card of the shuffedCards array:

```
if (currentCard == 1) {
    [compHandDictionary setObject:[[highCardDictionary 
                      valueForKey:[shuffledCards objectAtIndex:currentCard]] intValue] 
                           forKey:[cardsShuffled objectAtIndex:currentCard]];
}
```

However this is not allowed because "int" to "id" is not allowed.

There might be a better way but I have not been able to find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

...

I got this to work by modifying jstevenco's answer. I created two arrays and formed a new dictionary for the computer hand of just the 15 cards. Then to sort I used:

```
NSArray* sortedKeys = [newDict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id     obj2) {

        if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Why you just don't use the original dictionary to get Card Values?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but since I'm creating the new dictionary from an Array that does not have the Card Values I haven't found the code that that can get the Card Values from the original dictionary

Comment: With currentCard from shuffledCards, I can get the Card Key and High Card values, but I need to figure out how to get those values into a new dictionary

Comment: But you are always talking about **new** dictionary. What about is you only had the only single dictionary with **all Card Key-Values**? From this dictionary you can get Card Values for any Card Keys regardless of where they are (in „computer's hand”, „shuffled card deck”, „user's hand”, wherever...).

Comment: Ok, this is my first time with dictionaries so let me rephrase.  I have a cardsArray which contains all the card names (52). I then have a computerCardsArray which only contains 15 of the original 52 card names. I also have a cardValues dictionary which has card values assigned for card names...I need a sorted array or dictionary that contains the 15 card names in the computerCardsArray that is sorted by cardValues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort a dictionary's keys using:

```
 NSArray* sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

If you then want to create a sorted array from this you can use:

```
 NSArray* objects = [dict objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: To say that "You can sort a dictionary based on its keys" is a bit inaccurate. Dictionaries themselves can't ever be sorted -- they're unordered collections. Sorting an array of keys doesn't sort the dictionary they were obtained from.

Comment: True -- my choice of wording is not accurate.  I was trying to convey the fact that it's relatively simple to retrieve objects in an ordered way from a dictionary.

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Comment: Understood, and thanks for editing your answer! It can really make a difference for folks who are new to the language.

Comment: Thanks all, however I am not trying to sort the dictionary by keys, I'm trying to sort the keys in the dictionary by their values

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains the name and value for a given card, for example like so:

```
NSArray *cards = @[@{@"name" : @"Queen", @"value" : @12},
                   @{@"name" : @"Jack", @"value" : @11},
                   @{@"name" : @"Ace", @"value" : @14},
                   @{@"name" : @"King", @"value" : @13}];
```

You could then easily sort the `cards` array as shown below:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedCards = [cards sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSLog(@"\n\n%@\n\n", sortedCards);
```

Output of the `NSLog` statement above would be as follows:

```
(
    {
        name = Jack;
        value = 11;
    },
        {
        name = Queen;
        value = 12;
    },
        {
        name = King;
        value = 13;
    },
        {
        name = Ace;
        value = 14;
    }
)
```

To obtain an array of card names, you could then simply send a `valueForKey:` message to the sorted array of card dictionaries:

```
NSArray *sortedNames = [sortedCards valueForKey:@"name"];

NSLog(@"\n\n%@\n\n", sortedNames);
```

The output of the preceding `NSLog` statement would be:

```
(
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
)
```